# windows 8 release preview and GRUB

Tags: windows, boot, bootloader, grub, mbr

On my pc I have Windows 7 on the primary partition, Linux Mint 12 on a logic partition and windows 8 release preview in an extended partition.

When I installed w8 it has overwritten GRUB and installed the w8 bootloader, which I don't like because it take some time to start up. 
I decided to restore the GRUB bootloader but when I choose windows 7 or windows 8 it started the Windows 8 bootloader that gave me the opportunity to log in Windows 7 or Windows 8.

I tried EasyBCD to fix this but now when I choose Windows 7 from the GRUB menu it starts up the windows 7 bootloader and if I choose windows 8 (in the GRUB menu) it fails. 
I tried (always with easybcd to erase the mbr and then to restore GRUB but I couldn't load windows (ntldr is missing error). 
With a recovery DVD I restored the windows 7 bootloader, but I am now stuck in the initial condition: if I choose from the GRUB menu windows 7 or windows 8 it starts the windows 7 bootloader.

Do you have any suggestion in order to fix this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Recently I got a similar problem and solved it when I use GRUB2. GRUB2 supports newer hard  disk when GRUB has problem with it and the error message isn't very helpful but it's difficult to install because it's new.